# Express server doesn't respond correctly when hosted in a remote server, as I am using React Redux locally to get data of Express app remotely

Tags: json, reactjs, http, express, redux

I have these functions, one is on the server and the other is on the client.

Node Express code:

```
app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
        res.send(req.user);
    });
```

React Redux code:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${URI}/api/current_user`);

    console.log("res data: " +res.data)

    dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

The problem is that I get null as output of `console.log("res data: " +res.data)` as this `{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`. But I get JSON when testing on the browser as https://server243.azurewebsites.net/api/current_user.

When I have bothe server and clien running locally, I get data as output of `console.log("res data: " +res.data)`

Comment: React redux part is completely irrelevant to your problem. Just saying

Comment: please suggest the tags

Comment: Simply put, your express server doesn't respond correctly when hosted in a remote server. You can ask why. Meanwhile, let me think what could have caused that problem

Comment: You can do a simple test to narrow down the problem. Check the `req.user` from the server side. Add `console.log(req.user)` above the `res.send` statement and check the terminal console in the server side

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Sorry to do that, as I already mentioned I get data in the browser with same URI!

Comment: What do you mean by " I get data". `req.user` will exist only if you create a session. Are you using express session or some other middleware? If so, anyone who needs to call the above request should first create a session by calling some other endpoint. If you are already doing that, the problem is probably in that endpoint

Comment: I mean by saying "I get data" is that I get JSON response as mentioned. And that is user record as object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161932/discussion-between-diamond-and-pubudu-dodangoda).

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda how can I know from my code if I am using express session? I am a beginner and had this project boilerplate from an article.

Comment: I am on chat.  Come join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was discussed in the chat, the problem is not in the react application.

The req.user object is created usually by PassportJs. So for passportJs to do that, you must first make your react application call the Oauth provider (google) in your case. Then the provider will direct users to a screen where they can use their user name and password to login.

Upon successful authentication, the registered endpoint in your express app will be called by the auth provider, which will eventually establish a valid session between the user's browser and your express server.

Then req.user will contain the passportJs deserialized data.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse of [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
When you do request on the local mashine, all (server and client) are localhost and all is fine. When you try to acces remote server - it blocked yor request, becouse server and client are not from the same domain

try add this middleware to your express server

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, MOVE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

Comment: res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
is only needed and I mentioned it, I have already tried other headers but didn't make a difference! so I removed them to be brief.

Comment: @Diamond try to replace `res.send(req.user);` with `res.end(req.user);`

Comment: let me check that and brb!

Comment: I got Internal Server Error at chrome browser. And still get the same {data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …} as mentioned above.